# Why does my Kotlin compilation fail using Kotlin-Maven-Plugin?

Tags: maven, kotlin

While trying to compile a Java/Kotlin hybrid project, I received the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.3-2:compile (compile) on project tablesaw-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2529)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:777)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:51)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.computeAllSystemModules$kotlin_compiler(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:28)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.computeRootModules(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:298)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.addModularRoots(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:277)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.convertClasspathRoots(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:269)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:197)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:109)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:423)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:240)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:230)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:189)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execCompiler(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:236)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:184)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:43)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:219)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
[ERROR] at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I am using Maven 3.3.9 with Kotlin 1.1.3-2, and Java 1.8

In googling for similar problems I saw similar results from other code using ClassReader. Those issues were attributed to a version mismatch, but the examples were not using Kotlin and I think my versions are ok.

My pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>tech.tablesaw</groupId>
    <artifactId>tablesaw-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>tablesaw-core</artifactId>
<version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>test-jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Based on the message you are trying to run on JDK 9 and not on JDK 8...see `java.base@9-ea/Native Method...`?

Comment: that was indeed the problem. thanks. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Apart from that you shouldn't define all plugins in your pom file cause the build life cycle defines them...or maybe making it better define them including the version of the plugin in a pluginManagement part instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This build is running on JDK9 and not on JDK 8 as mentioned based on the log output you can see things like this:

```
java.base@9-ea/Native Method...
```

which is the hint about JDK 9 usage.